# Permalink settings are stuck on https, will not update to http

Tags: permalinks

One of my sites, which use to be https, has been changed to http, but the permalink setting on the WP dashboard still says https:// and will not revert to http.
The SSL certificate has been revoked & removed (Letscrypt/ Nginx server). The site's nginx config confirms this, only port 80 is listed.

The following have been checked:

1. Under General settings, the Wordpress & Site url have been changed to http
2. When that didn't work I added the following to wp-config
   define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
   define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/wp-content' );

then I added following to the themes function.php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );

Still no joy. I ran a search & replace https with http on the DB, again no change.
I can load the site if I paste the url with http into the address bar, but clicking any link on the site reverts to https.

I can only assume there's a borked setting somewhere in the DB, but I can't find it. Any help on this perplexing problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at any htaccess files in your site that might be doing the rewrite to https? It may also be forced by your hosting place. (Although I am not sure why you don't want to have https - there are SEO penalties for not having SSL enabled on your site. Some browsers won't even load the site.)

Comment: Thanks, but there's no .htaccess with nginx. The nginx config for the site is set to http. I'm hosting on DO, and this is only site with issue.  As for https vs http SEO, yes I'm aware, but I have reasons unrelated to SEO for wanting http on this site.